# Unable to initialize Intel HD graphics driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics, switchable-graphics

I have a ASUS K52JC model notebook. It has double graphics cards, the one is "Intel HD Graphics", the another one is "Nvidia GeForce 310M". Nvidia graphics card uses "Nvidia Optimus Technology" which facilitates switching between graphics cards according to performance needs of an application.

Having some compatibility problems with older games, I decided to disable this switching technology in order to get only Nvidia card to be used. Eventually, I uninstalled Intel graphics card driver to disable it but It helped nothing because Nvidia card depends on Intel card. After then I installed Intel HD graphics drivers again.

Anyway, my actual problem is Intel graphics card driver is not initialized by Windows 7. I'm getting the error code :
`Windows cannot initialize the device driver for this hardware. (Code 37)`. I tried reinstalling and updating device driver several times, also running system file checker. Remarkably, I had a system restore attempt that resulted in failure.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem? How can I analyze the system further to solve this problem? Is there any tool to diagnose this situation?

Comment: Have you tried using [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to go back to the restore point before you removed the intel drivers?  This is a built-in feature in Windows and unless you intentionally turned it off then you should be able to go back.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned it. I tried restoring the system to all available restore points using System Restore but all have failed.

Comment: where are you aquiring the intel grafics driver from?  With Asus , you should probably get it from Asus, making sure you have the exact correct model and all. start there http://www.asus.com/ to account for any regional difference, then go to "Support" at the top of the page, then to "self support" "drivers" then enter your K52JC  then enter your correct OS.

Comment: I've already acquired the driver from the original manufacturer's site which is Asus.com. I haven't used a driver other than it. And I'm afraid this is a part of the problem.

Comment: I've recently used ComboFix malware cleaning utility to remove some malicious programs from my computer. I've heard about Combofix that it deletes some system files which is necessary and thus system integrity is broken. Can Combofix cause such a driver problem because of deletion of system files.

Comment: When I Tested it long ago. ComboFix makes changes to the system beyond removal. normally it would not "damage the system", and what I saw should not cause a driver issues. There are good reasons why they say do not run ComboFix unless expert tells you to, but even the expert isnt going to see everything in your machine and how it was effected.  If your running combofix to being with . . . well then you probably had a problem, and all problems you have may not be all solved either.